# Resetting and changing speed on SKActions

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, velocity, skaction

Is there a way to change the velocity/speed of a skaction and also to reset the skaction?

```
let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(5.0)

let moveRight = SKAction.moveByX(300, y:0, duration: 1.0)

let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, moveRight])

let endlessAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence)

node.runAction(endlessAction)
```

This code works but the things i would like to change is how fast the `SKSpriteNode` moves to the right as at the moment it it quite slow and also to make the `SKSpriteNode` return to its orignal position rather than keep on moving to right forever?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `velocity = distance / time`, decreasing the `duration` will increase the speed the the sprite will move across the screen.

Regarding your second point, by considering how `SKAction.moveByX(300, y:0, duration: 1.0)` moves the node to the right; `SKAction.moveByX(-300, y:0, duration: 1.0)` must therefore move the node to the left, back to its original position.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's great Thank you! Do you know a way so instead of the nodes going off the screen and coming back on the screen the same way, you can instead make the nodes go to the right which we have done, but then come onto the screen from the left side? So goes off the right hand side of the screen and comes back on the left?

Comment: Oh, is that what you mean when you wrote "return to its orignal position rather than keep on moving to right forever"?

Comment: No your information helped a lot! Instead I went back -600 then +300 to get back to the middle.

Comment: Awesome :) If you looking to wrap the screen and have your node appear back on the left after moving to the right, I would recommend you post a new question - I don't believe there are any other questions specifically on it regarding Sprite Kit (or at least, I can't find any).